# What is the equivalent to WinSock in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, tcp, winsock, ipad

I need to communicate with a hardware device using TCP and with Windows I would use WinSock.

What is the equivalent library that I can use from the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything like winsock per-se, there is Objective-C wrappers around POSIX Sockets, like NSUrl and the like. This ([Network Programming - iPhone SDK](http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html)) might help with getting an idea about what is available.

Answer (score 2):

WinSock is Window's version of the BSD socket. iPhoneOS being Darwin having a BSD user-land of course has a socket API (`<sys/socket.h>` etc) too.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets.

In CoreFoundation there is also a higher level API called [CFSocket](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html). (The Foundation version, NSSocketPort, is not available on iPhoneOS.)